# MVC: How to set the base url for web page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC and webgrid. I have a controller **MasterDetail** and an ActionResult **Index**. The header links have format like:

```
http://foo:5321/Site/MasterDetail?sort=DRUG_CODE&sortdir=ASC
```

When clicked, the **Index** ActionResult is invoked. So far, so good.

In another controller the same page is rendered using the ActionResult **AfterTemplate**.

```
   return RedirectToAction("AfterTemplate", "MasterDetail");
```

The resulting header Urls look like:

```
http://foo:5321/SyntheticData/MasterDetail/AfterTemplate?sort=DRUG_VOCAB&sortdir=ASC
```

Now when the headers are clicked, handling fails (**AfterTemplate** is added to the urls)

Is there a way to set the base url of a page using the MVC controller ? I have no control of how webgrid creates it's url's.

I have run into this issue with other pages, and I am always having to do some kind of JScript to correct the page after loading (lame!)

Comment: Why do you use two different action for the same page: Index and AfterTempalte?

Comment: It seems to me, that saving and loading templates belong in one controller - while displaying data belongs in another.